# how to SetState the child class from parent class in flutter

Tags: class, flutter, parent, setstate

i want to set the state of child class ( Stateful ) from parent class ( statefull ) in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, anytime you call `setState` in a widget, it automatically rebuilds all the children. Therefore, all you need to do is call `setState` in the parent widget